# MongoDB UpdateOne is not updating a record

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am experiencing really weird behavior when trying to update a single record. I use UpdateOne() method and it works as expected in 99% of cases BUT sometimes I get the following results:
[image]
As you can see, MongoDB was able to find my record but it wasn't updated. I've tried to change write concern, which accordingly to the docs, might help:

```
collection.WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.WMajority.With(journal: true))
```

but it didn't.

Here is how I update my records:

```
collection.UpdateOne(x => x.Id == _myObject.Id.AsObjectId, updateDef);
```

Update definition:

```
var updateDef = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<IndexedProfileData>().Set(x => x.Property.ChildCollection, newCollection);
```

I would be really appreciated if somebody could explain me why this is happening and how to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will not update a document if it's already in its "updated" state.

For example, using the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.test.find()
{"_id": 0, "a": 0}

> db.test.update({_id:0}, {$set:{a:1}})
WriteResult({
  "nMatched": 1,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nModified": 1
})
```

Since `a` is `0` and we're setting `a` to `1`, the update modified the document (`nMatched: 1`, `nModified: 1`).

```
> db.test.find()
{"_id": 0, "a": 1}

> db.test.update({_id:0}, {$set:{a:1}})
WriteResult({
  "nMatched": 1,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nModified": 0
})
```

If we're trying to set `a` to `1` again, the update statement found the document, but realized that it doesn't need to do any work (`nMatched: 1`, `nModified: 0`).

Comment: Aha! I thought about this as well but wasn't sure. Thx a lot!